# How to program a Yes/No answer as buttons in an HTML form, without using radio buttons or checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, forms, boolean

How do you program the following in a webform:

Are you male or female?

[image]

Comment: You can add two button with image male and female and when click on any button the another button is become disable and the button will be click on is take value.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a clear problem statement. Please read the question. And thanks for the down vote. Do you need me to add 2 pictures with the up and down states? The answerer didn't have any problem understanding it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simulate using the labels of radio buttons.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

label {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: thin solid darkorange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: darkblue;
    cursor: default;
    color: #E6E6E6;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle-on" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="toggle-on">On</label>
<input id="toggle-off" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="toggle-off">Off</label>
```

Comment: How do I style the label when the radio button is checked?

Comment: One typo. Please check again.

Comment: Is it possible to have them unchecked by default, and only have the checked effect when they are clicked? Thanks for your time!